# What's the Spring Cloud Gateway equivalent to Netflix Zuuls shouldFilter method?

Tags: java, spring, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm migrating from Netflix Zuul to Spring Cloud Gateway and can't find an equivalent to Netflix Zuuls shouldFilter method. Is there no equivalent?

Netflix Zuul code I want to replace:

```java
@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true; // Yes run this filter!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do an if clause in the Spring Cloud Gateway filter method.

Example:

```java
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    if(someCondition == false) {
        return chain.filter(exchange); // Skip this filter and continue to the next filter
    }

    // More filter code
}
```